# sending android mobile sms to asp.net server via REST/JSON or ksoap?

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services

I want to create online backup of my sms on server. which web service is better either REST or SOAP. I searched this thing alot, but I am unable to find out which web service suits my application best.

Answer (score 0):

I think ksoap would be best for Android; it's methods are pretty easy and it has good serialization.